# What's the most cots efficient way to store self-hosted webservices as a small company?

Tags: sysadmin

I am currently creating a web development business with some partners.
We want to have more and more self-hosted apps, in order to own our data, and be extremely cost effective.
Our goal is to pay the least possible, because we want to keep being small.

Currently, we are self hosting a Mattermost instance in a small VPS, but here is a non-complete list of what we would like to host, ideally : Wekan, Taiga, Bitwarden, Nextcloud, Roundcube, GitLab, Matomo, etc...

I would like to know what would be the most cost effective way to host this, considering we don't have expert sysadmin skill, just basic/intermediate knowledge.

As far as I know, we could choose :

- a dedicated server, like 8/16cores, 32 RAM storage, etc... and use docker containers to start services. It could cost us little, but we have to manage everything : updates, backups, etc... I'm not sure we would have the time to manage this kind of server.
- using Cloud services like AWS/GCP/Azure. In this case, It will cost us more, but less to manage
- using services like DigitalOcean, even more expensive but even less management
- ...

Could you share you advice about our case ? What would be the less expensive for us, not only considering the "compute unit" part, but the whole system whith backups, updates, etc?

Thank you a lot for sharing ;)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), hosting advice, approaches etc.